# Вывести все строки из нулей и единиц длины N, содержащие ровно K единиц

Tags: pascal

По данным числам N и K выведите все строки из нулей и единиц длины N, содержащие ровно K единиц, в лексикографическом порядке.

Формат входных данных

Заданы 2 числа: N и K (0≤K≤N, 0≤N≤100)

Формат выходных данных

Необходимо вывести все строки из нулей и единиц длины N, содержащие ровно K единиц, в лексикографическом порядке. Гарантируется, что размер ответа не превышает 10MiB.

Пример

```
Ввод        Вывод       
 4 2         0011
             0101
             0110
             1001
             1010
             1100
```

Вот моя идея (моя идея проходит 59 из 62 тестов, 3 теста больше 1 секунды работают)

```
    var
      kol : array[1..101] of Byte;
      n,k : Byte;
        s : String[120];
procedure vivod(sum:Byte);
var i:Byte;
begin
      Write(copy(s,1,n-(sum+k))); // вывод ведущих нулей
      for i := 1 to k do
            Write('1',copy(s,1,kol[i])); //вывод 1 а следом kol[i] - кол-во нулей идущих за этой единицей
      WriteLn;
end;
procedure perebor;
var loc,sum,i,id,x:Byte;
begin
      sum:=0;
      vivod(sum); //вывод начально перестановки (000...1111)
      while kol[k]<n-k do //когда после последней единицы будет стоять n-k нулей, т.е. больше нулей не может стоять, завершить перебор
      begin
            inc(sum);// кол-во нулей которых ставится первоночально после 1 единицы
                 i := 1;
                 fillchar(kol,n,0); //у всех других единиц кол-во нулей 0
            kol[1] := sum;         // после первой единицы должно стоять sum нулей    
            while kol[k]<>sum do   // пока sum нулей не окажется у последней единицы перебирать
            begin
                  vivod(sum);  //вывести очередную перестановку
                  if i=k then // если мы дошли до последний(k-ой единицы)
                  begin
                        x:=kol[k]; //запоминаем кол-во единиц стоящих после последней единицы
                        kol[k]:=0; //обнуляем его, ведь увеличивать некуда
                        while kol[i-1]=0 do dec(i); //находим такую первую единицу у которой не стоят нули
                        kol[i]:=x; //присваем ей кол-во которое было у последнего элемента
                        dec(i); // уменьшаем указатель на предыдущий элемент
                  end;
                   {таким образом я уменьшаю kol нулей у i единицы, и увеличиваю кол-во нулей у следующей единицы}
                  dec(kol[i]);
                  inc(i);
                  inc(kol[i]);
            end;
            vivod(sum);  // вывожу перестановку последнюю когда массив kol=[0,0,0,..,0,0,sum]
      end;
end;
begin
      Assign(input,'input.txt');
      Reset(input);
          REadLn(n,k);
          {чтобы выводить ведущие нули или нули между единицами не используя циклы, а тупо copy}
          s:='0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
      close(input);

      Assign(output,'output.txt');
      ReWrite(output);
      perebor;
      close(output);
end.
```

Comment: Да, я это для себя решаю! Могу даже свою идею и решение написать! Но это сделано коряво.

Comment: Похоже на олимпиадную задачку.

Решение в лоб: 

идти по всем двоичным числам до максимального с K единицами в начале и N-K нулями, и проверять кол-во единиц в каждом числе, если оно равно K, заносить в ответ, если нет - идти дальше.

Comment: Евгений, действительно напишите свою идею - далее будем смотреть. P.S. Мысли тоже появились, но давно уже сдавал экзамен по данной тематике :).

Comment: разьяснил как мог, читайте! не проходит 3 теста и то только по времени

Comment: Евгений, извините, я написал: дай идею - буду смотреть. Но сейчас идет матч Евро 2012 :). Если у Вас есть время до понедельника, то скиньте мне еще раз Вашу задачу на freestas@email.ua - я постараюсь решить. Но уже сейчас мне ясно, что необходимо задавать строковую переменную длины N, а далее "толкать" единицы в право с учетом разрядности K и достижения конца строки. Хотя, чувствую, существует универсальный математический алгоритм решения подобной задачи.

Comment: @Евгений536, похоже на вопрос из **`Online Judge`**.

> Могу привести код на **`Visual Basic`**, если сможете на **`Pascal`** перевести

Comment: @Spectre вот это тебя не туда понесло. По всем числам идти это 2^100 проверок при N=100

Comment: @rasmisha: Ха! А представляете если будет тест 100 1, чтобы найти эти 100 вариант размещения одной 1, придется перебирать 2^100 вариантов! прикол

Comment: так я и не утверждал, что это хорошее решение, наиболее оптимальная по-моему идея тов. [@Вячеслава Кириченко](http://hashcode.ru/users/4185/вячеслав-кириченко)

Comment: @Евгений536, не хочется говорить на вас плохо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  ones: array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
  K: Integer;
  N: Integer;
  S: String;
  input, output: TextFile;
  procedure shiftones(idx: Integer);
  begin
    if (Idx<K-1) and (ones[Idx+1]=ones[Idx]+1) then 
    begin
      shiftones(Idx+1);//двигаем индекс старшей единицы
      ones[Idx]:=Idx;//а текущий индекс возвращаем на начало. начало совпадает с индексом
    end
    else
      ones[Idx]:=ones[Idx]+1;//двигаем индекс текущей единицы
  end;
  function CurStr: String;
  var
    ii: Integer;
  begin
    Result:=S;
    for ii:=0 to K-1 do
      Result[N-ones[ii]]:='1';//вписываем единицы в индексы по массиву (с конца)
  end;
begin
  AssignFile(input,'input.txt');
  Reset(input);
  ReadLn(input,N,K);
  closeFile(input);
  S:='';
  for i:=0 to N-1 do S:=S+'0';//Строка нулей
  SetLength(ones,K);
  for i:=0 to Length(ones)-1 do ones[i]:=i; //Массив индексов единиц
  AssignFile(output,'output.txt');
  ReWrite(output);
  while (ones[K-1]<N) do
  begin
    WriteLn(output,CurStr);
    shiftones(0);//Двигаем единицы
  end;
  closeFile(output);
end.
```

При N=22 и K=11 (максимальное количество строк будет для n при k=n/2) время 0.731, размер файла 16,1MB, т.е. больше чем нужно.

Comment: классное решение, но оно не проходит 10 тестов, ошибка выполнения говорит! буду думать где ошибка

Comment: Ошибки данной программы: не учитывался случай что может быть k=0 и может быть n=0; Спасибо за данный код!

Comment: Да, граничные условия не проверял. Ну поправить несложно, главное принцип ясен.